# Java: How does passing uninstantiated object references work?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, pass-by-value

Here's an example of what I mean.

If I have a binary tree insert method that accepts a node, and I pass it parent.child (which is uninstantiated) what exactly is being passed?

Since Java is pass by value it must be passing a copy of the reference but without any object to point to what will happen? Does that mean I'm passing an empty reference that has no relevance to the parent node?

Unfortunately I don't have any code since this was actually a question that was passed onto me and I couldn't quite put it together. My solution was to pass a parent node which is already instantiated and then instantiate parent.child

Comment: I'm not sure just what you mean.  But any reference, whether it's an instance member or a static member or a local variable, is automatically initialized to `null` until you assign something else to it.  If you pass it as a parameter, the parameter will be `null`.

Comment: If something isn't instantiated, it is initialized to it's default value. False for booleans, 0 for most other primatives, and null for reference types. So yes, you will be passing a pointer that points to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. Consider the type

```
class Node {
    Node child;
}

Node parent = new Node();
// here, parent.child == null
```

So, assuming `null` is a special value, say 0x0000, somewhere in memory (YMMV), there's a

```
0x1000: Start of Node Object
0x1004: 0x0000 (child field offset)
...
0x6000: 0x1000 (parent variable)
```

In other words, there's a `Node` object, with a `child` field storing `null` as its value. Additionally, there's a variable `parent` storing the value (an address of sorts) of the `Node` object.

When you do

```
public void insert(Node node) {/* implementation */}
...
tree.insert(parent.child);
```

You're dereferencing `parent`, thereby getting its address, `0x1000`, figuring out at which offset its `child` field is, `0x1004`, and getting its value, `0x0000`. You then copy that value on the stack. The method invocation will pop that value from the stack and bind it to this new `node` variable. So now you have

```
0x1000: Start of Node Object
0x1004: 0x0000 (child field offset) // null
...
0x6000: 0x1000 (parent variable)
...
0x8000: 0x0000 (node variable) // null
```

To answer your question

> Does that mean I'm passing an empty reference that has no relevance to
>   the parent node?

You're passing a `null` reference. There will be no way to retrieve whatever `parent` was referencing from the bound parameter.